# How to compile ast node in 'eval' mode

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to create a code object that I would be able to reuse with `eval` later on. I need to do this based on some `ast` nodes I have programmatically generated, therefore I can't have code as a string passed to `compile` function. How to construct a valid `ast` node for compile? Below are couple of things I have tried:

```
tree = ast.parse("2+2")
exe = compile(tree.body[0], filename="", mode="eval")
```

> TypeError: expected Expression node, got Expr

```
tree = ast.BinOp(left=ast.Num(n=2), right=ast.Num(n=2), op=ast.Add())
exe = compile(tree, filename="", mode="eval")
```

> TypeError: expected Expression node, got BinOp

```
tree = ast.BinOp(left=ast.Num(n=2), right=ast.Num(n=2), op=ast.Add())
expr = ast.Expression(body=[tree])
ast.fix_missing_locations(expr)
exe = compile(expr, filename="", mode="eval")
```

> TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from expr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last attempt is close, but the `body` of `ast.Expression` should be a single expression, not a list of expressions.

Change:

```
expr = ast.Expression(body=[tree])
```

to:

```
expr = ast.Expression(body=tree)
```

so that `eval(exe)` returns: `4`